# getting the output of delete statement in UDF in postgres

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql

In Postgres in a user defined function I do

```
execute format('delete from table where session_id = %L', id);
```

ran without `execute` postgres (may) return(s) the following:

```
DELETE 0
```

Is there any way I could get this output in the user defined function? What I am looking is something like:

```
execute format('delete from table where session_id = %L', id) into log;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `GET DIAGNOSTICS` command for this purpose.  A quick example:

```
DO $$
DECLARE i integer; 
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM event1;
    GET DIAGNOSTICS i = ROW_COUNT;
    RAISE NOTICE 'DELETE %', i;
END;
$$;
```

For DELETE statements, the only useful variable is `ROW_COUNT`, for `INSERT`s there is also `RESULT_OID`.

Set the error level after the `RAISE` to your choice and set the logging configuration accordingly.

Comment: The point is that I also use user defined functions, that generate 'raise notice' output. Would be cool to catch that too..